# How to get exact decimal values on dividing numbers in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get exact decimal values on dividing numbers in SQL?

Example : Dividing 8 over 25 will return 0.32.

I will have to get the exact decimals.

Comment: Not sure I understand. `SELECT 8.0 / 25.0;` returns `0.320000`; why is that not correct? You can't have different values for scale and precision in a single column; if not displaying trailing 0's is important then you should be handling that in your presentation layer.

Comment: 8.0/25.0  otherwise it's doing integer math which rounds.  the result of an int divided by an int is an int, not a decimal.  Alternatively define each value as decimal with precision and scale.

Comment: @Larnu , i have integers as 8  and 25 in the database. i just realized that, i will have to convert them to decimal to get the decimal value

Comment: SELECT 8 / (25+0.0)

Comment: Correct. An expression containing **only** integers will return an integer. If you need to return a `decimal`, you need to implicitly/explicitly convert *at least* one of the values to a `decimal`.

Comment: You can use CONVERT OR CAST one of the integer values. SELECT CAST(8 AS NUMERIC(18,6))/25, CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,6),8) / 25

Comment: Thanks.. if i need to have only 2 decimals ??  we just need only 2 decimal units. How to get the value only as .32 and not .32000

Comment: it can't always do so, for example 1.0/3.0 or 22.0 / 7.0 will truncate the recurring values to a finite number of places

Comment: select cast(100 - ( (CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2),8)) / (CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2),25))) as varchar(10)) + '%'  As PercentageScore    -- I am working on percentage concept. I will have to have only 2 digit units

Comment: Thanks,, this is completed..

Comment: Decimal precision and scale (4,2) gives allows for 99.99 but no more.   Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2  If possible I"d make sure the datatype of these fields in your database are of the correct datatype and not just "int"